# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.06"

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been trying to make a simple program in eclipse for a school project, but I keep getting this after I enter my interest rate. I am relatively new to coding and programming in general, and java is new to me as of this month so any help is appreciated. The code is this:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Interest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Input ============================

    System.out.println("Initial loan total:");     //cost
    String cost;
    cost = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Down payment:");     //down
    String down;
    down = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Length of term:");     //term
    String term;
    term = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Interest rate (decimal form):");     //rate
    String rate;
    rate = in.nextLine();

    int principle1 = Integer.parseInt(cost) - Integer.parseInt(down);

    String hundred;
    hundred = "100";

    int interest = Integer.parseInt(rate) * Integer.parseInt(hundred);

    //Output ===========================

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.format("%tB %td, %tY", c,c,c);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The initial cost of the loan is $" + cost);
    System.out.println("The down payment is $" + down);
    System.out.println("The principle is $" + principle1);
    System.out.println("The term is " + term + " months");
    System.out.println("The interest rate is " + interest + "%");
    System.out.println("The monthly patments are $");

    in.close();
}

}
```

When I run the program it lets me put in the initial loan, down payment and length of term but as soon as I put in 0.06 for the interest rate it gives me the error message. I would also like to point out that I have a limited understanding of how the math in my code works.

Comment: You parse the value to an integer. But 0.06 is a double or float

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` cannot parse floating point numbers.

Comment: `int` is an integer type, which means it can only contain whole numbers. I suggest looking into a Java tutorial where you can learn about the basic types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you are trying to parse 0.06 to **Integer** and 0.06 is **float**.
use `Float.parseFloat(rate);` and your interest should be a float too `float interest`